# Fill in the parentheses

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

$()+()+()+()+()=30$

**How can you fill in the parentheses with the numbers $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13$ to make the above equation true?** Repeats are allowed, but you must fill in all of the parentheses!

Bonus if you already solved this:

> Can you do it without extra symbols? (no +, -, ÷, ｘ, <<, !, etc.)

(**EDIT:** You don't have to use all of the numbers.)

**EDIT2**: Okay, the answer is not that there is no answer.  I'm not looking for a mathematical proof here.

**EDIT3**: The above information is all you need to solve the problem. Be creative!

One possible solution:

> $(5+1)+(5+1)+(5+1)+(5+1)+(5+1)=30$

My favorite solution:

> ${{5}\choose{3}}$+(5)+(5)+(5)+(5)=30

Comment: must we use all the numbers?

Comment: Please clarify if it is just one number per pair of parantheses? You say repeats are allowed, and the hint makes me think that you can use operators.. so can I put (9-7) + (..) and so on?

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking, and i start to think u do not know either and i am voting for close...

Comment: @Oray If you're not sure, I'd suggest you look at existing answers.

Comment: What exactly are you unclear on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is:

> (3!) + (9) + (7) + (3) + (5) = 30

For Bonus:

> sum of 5 odd numbers is ALWAYS an odd number so it is not possible unless something is done. What I am doing is using the number 9 as BASE.

so;

> (13) + (11) + (5) + (3) + (1) = 33 , base9 (**33**) = base10 (**30**)

or a more direct way with that logic;

> (7+5+5+5+5)base9 = (30)base9

Comment: I edited the bonus part; check again. The first answer is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

One answer:

> Using base 11: 1 + 3 + 3 + 11 + 13 = 30
>  Equivalent in base 10
>  1 + 3 + 3 + 12 + 14 = 33

Second one:

> Using base 13: 1 + 3 + 5 + 11 + 13 = 30
>  Equivalent in base 10
>  1 + 3 + 5 + 14 + 16 = 39

And a third one:

> Because you cannot add 5 odd numbers to get an even number in base 10 you have to use tricks.
>  3 + 5 + 3! + 7 + 9 = 30
>  equivalent to
>  3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 30

**[EDIT]**
Bonus one or two:

> Using base 9: 1 + 1 + 3 + 11 + 13 = 30
>  Equivalent in base 10:
>  1 + 1 + 3 + 10 + 12 = 27
>
>
>  Using base 7: 1 + 1 + 1 + 11 + 13 = 30
>  Equivalent in base 10:
>  1 + 1 + 1 + 8 + 10 = 21

Answer (score 1):

I remember solving similar question before:

> By putting number 9 upside down, i get (13)+(7)+(6)+(3)+(1)=30